# How do you get "1" as integer in if-else statement rather than as boolean in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to use MATLAB FUNCTION block in simulink .

The model is shown below [image]

In the "time_calc" Function i want to manipulate the variable "Sector" as shown in the code below

```
if sector == 1 || 2
     sec = 1
elseif sector == 3 || 4
     sec = 2

elseif sector == 5||6
     sec = 3
elseif sector == 7||8
    sec = 4
elseif sector == 9||10
    sec = 5
elseif sector == 11 || 12
    sec = 6
 
end
```

The below is the scope and you can see the values of "sector" changing from 0 through 12 and then repeating itself

[image: Scope for values of "Sector"]

But I am getting the value of "sec" as constant "1"(shown below in figure)
(Maybe because it is evaluating the first "1" as boolean true and running that statement only over and over again)
[image]
How to correct it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if sector == 1 || 2` evaluates `sector == 1`, if it's true, the statement is true. If it's false, it evaluates `2`, which is always true, and so the statement is always true.

What  you intended to write was `if sector == 1 || sector == 2`. You can also write this as `if any(sector == [1, 2])`.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is equivalent to:

```
sec=ceil(sector/2)
```

@Cris Luengo's answer shows why your code is wrong. But I suggest you change the entire thing by this one liner, that is much clearer.

Comment: Damn, I just thought of the same thing... :(

Comment: WoW . Fixes it up and does everything nicely . Thanks .

Comment: With this in mind, it also shouldn't be a MATLAB Function block, since this is trivial to do with actual Simulink blocks

Comment: I mostly use matlab function blocks in my pulse width modulation for the ease of calculations and reducing the total size of the system . Also , simulink blocks need delay blocks sometimes while matlab functions don't. 

Are there are advantages in blocks over functions ?

Comment: @Trickk simulinks blocks are better. They are tied to the simulation loop in a native way such that the optimizer can perhaps add them to previous and next blocks together to run faster. MATLAB blocks, in some sense, require the simulation to stop, run the code, then start again. 

Basically, everything you can do in simulink, you can do in MATLAB, and viceversa, just better to stick with the native system as much as you can. If "the size of the system" you mean the visual clutter (MATLAB blocks will make code that is larger) then just use subblocks!

Answer (score -2):

Remove the elseif's and replace them all with just if's

Comment: If you do this, you will always end up with `sec = 6`, no matter what the value of `sector` was.